# snprintf negative/zero value of buffer size

Tags: c, printf, buffer

If a negative number or 0 is passed as the second argument to `snprintf()`, will it write at the provided buffer position. Want to have the views that this should not result in any unexpected behavior.

```
int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);
```

Comment: `size_t` is unsigned....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing `0` to `snprintf` no char will be inserted into `dest` buffer.

Passing a negative number to a `size_t` parameter, which is `unsigned`, you are  passing a very big number as `size`.

Try

```
printf("%zu\n%zu\n", (size_t)(-1),  SIZE_MAX);
```

So with negative size parameter you can write a lot of bytes more that real dest buffer size, that in other words is Undefined Behavior/buffer overflow.

Answer (score 9):

Quoting `C11`, chpater §7.21.6.5, *The `snprintf()` function*

> `int snprintf(char * restrict s, size_t n,const char * restrict format, ...);`
>
> [...] If `n` is zero, nothing is written,
>   and `s` may be a null pointer.

So, in case you pass 0, nothing is written.

In case if you pass a `-`ve value, it may create issues, as the second argument, is of type `size_t` which is `unsigned`. So, the signed value will be treated as `unsigned` producing a unwanted size. This may cause issues (memory overrun) as the size is likely to be more than the supplied buffer can handle, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
. Nevertheless, as long as the buffer is large enough to be able to hold the supplied data, the supplied data will be written to the buffer.

From §7.19, `<stddef.h>`

> `size_t`
>   which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator;

Answer (score 4):

While the existing answers are correct when saying that no bytes will be written to the destination buffer when a size of 0 is given, they fail to inform you that, in this case, the return value of `snprintf` will be the sum of the sizes of your formatting parameters. Realizing this can come quite handy at times :)

From the manual:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> Upon successful return, these functions return the number
> of characters printed (excluding  the null byte used to end output to
> strings).
>
> The  functions snprintf() and vsnprintf() do not write more than size
> bytes (including the ter‐ minating null byte ('\0')).  **If the output
> was truncated due to this  limit,  then  the  return value  is  the
> number of characters (excluding the terminating null byte) which would
> have been written to the final string if enough space had been
> available.**  Thus, a return value  of  size or more means that the
> output was truncated.  (See also below under NOTES.)
>
> If an output error is encountered, a negative value is returned.